# restore backup files in another server using duplicity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, restore, duplicity

I am using duplicity to backup the application files with gpg key to Amazon service S3 server. And then restore the same from S3 to own server. I want to restore the backed up files to another separate server. is it possible? Please help..

Answer (score 0):

simply run duplicity on the other box and restore from your backend as you would on your own server.

..ede/duply.net

Comment: gpg key is unique per server. so can not restore in another server from S3. tried to export and import gpg key from server1 to server2 for restoring in server2. but nothing happened when running duplicity restore.

Comment: Anyone please help here? i want to do the backup securely using gpg key and restore in another server.